# Does Salesforce Dataloader affect Daily Async Apex Executions Limits?

Tags: data-loader

Just curious, does Salesforce dataloader affect the governor limit called Daily Async Apex Execution?

Dataloader settings:
Bulk API off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Async Apex Executions limit covers Batchables, Queueables, Future methods and scheduled Apex. For more information see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#in_topic_non_transactional_gov_limits_section).

Of course, if there are any triggers that run as a result of your data load, and those triggers launch any asynchronous Apex, then that will use up some of the limit.